# Is there a more elegant way to write my object hierarchical analyzer in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am learning Ruby and I wrote a simple function which returns the meta-model hierarchy of a variable.

```
def hiearchicalanalyzer(victim)
    if(victim.respond_to?('superclass'))
        if(victim.superclass == BasicObject)
            puts victim.superclass
        else
            puts victim.superclass
            hiearchicalanalyzer(victim.superclass)
        end
    else
        puts victim.class
        hiearchicalanalyzer(victim.class)
    end
end

hiearchicalanalyzer(5)
```

Is there a more elegant way of writing this piece of code in Ruby?

Comment: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#readme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def hiearchicalanalyzer(object)
  puts klass = (Class === object) ? object : object.class
  hiearchicalanalyzer(klass.superclass) if klass.superclass
end
```

- It's not necessary to use `object.respond_to?('superclass')` just to make sure that object is class. Because class of class is always `Class`, you can use method [Object#is_a?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-is_a-3F) and write `object.is_a?(Class)` for the same purpose. Or equivalent `Class === object` using [Module#===](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D).
- `BasicObject.superclass` returns `nil` which acts like `false` in conditional statements. So when you build a recursion function, you can use it for termination.

Comment: thanks a lot I will mark it as an answer, it is concise and beautiful

Answer (score 1):

```
def hiearchicalanalyzer victim
  if victim.respond_to?('superclass')
    puts victim.superclass
    if victim.superclass != BasicObject
       hiearchicalanalyzer(victim.superclass)
    end
  else
    puts victim.class
    hiearchicalanalyzer(victim.class)
  end
end
```

..one easy simplification. You could put in a one liner for that `if` statement, but IMO that's not more "elegant". Also try to use 2-space tabs, and get rid of some of those parens.

You could also do

```
def hiearchicalanalyzer(victim)
  unless victim.respond_to?('superclass')
    puts victim.class
    hiearchicalanalyzer(victim.class)
    return
  end
  puts victim.class
  hiearchicalanalyzer(victim.superclass) unless victim.superclass == BasicObject
end
```

IMO I like the first one better, it's more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my version :)

```
def hiearchicalanalyzer(victim)
  return unless victim && victim != BasicObject
  target = if victim.respond_to?(:superclass)
    victim.superclass
  else
    victim.class
  end

  puts target
  hiearchicalanalyzer target
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's mine:

```
def hierarchical_analyzer(obj)
  puts c = obj.class
  while c.respond_to? :superclass
    puts c = c.superclass
  end
end
```